# How does ことはあっても connect this otherwise 2 part sentence into one?

Tags: grammar, syntax

> **獄長**：「な～に、馴れればここでの生活も満更ではないぞ。どうせ**シャバにいたところで他人様の迷惑になることはあっても役には立たない**ボンクラどもなんだからよ」
>
> **Warden**: Once you're used to it, life here isn't too bad. Here you trouble only useless fools....

I would like to know a more literal version of the bold part. My guess is either he is speaking or directly about the prisoners in question:

- "Either way, on the outside you were all a nuisance to others, however, in here you are only fools."

Or maybe:

- "In the outside world, there may be others who are annoyed but they are all blockheads."

Comment: Can you please spend at least a few moments of effort making your questions clear (i.e., clearly state what you're asking about) and easy-to-read (use formatting syntax like blockquotes and other things listed on https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: Well, this site doesn't really have good tools to do things like highlight, font changing, adding bullets, italics, underscoring, etc., so it's kinda hard to emphasize certain parts of the post without those nice features. Even to highlight something you have to use some sort of <> thing or whatever brackets... I'm pretty sure this site needs an html update or something, seeing as it uses a very antiquated Windows XP style 2002 word processing. My question, however, should be pretty obvious... the english title above is a rushed translation of the japanese sentence, but it is incomplete.

Comment: Uh, almost all of the things you listed are possible, did you follow the link I put in my previous comment? Also, proofreading/translation questions are considered off-topic, so if that’s what this is (as opposed to asking about a specific grammar point or word nuance) then this question is probably off-topic.

Comment: @SomaRise And did you know you are expected to [check the most helpful answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/719822)?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question and remove the sentences that were unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost everything before ボンクラ is a long relative clause that modifies ボンクラ. So the basic structure of the sentence is:

> どうせ *<long description here>* ボンクラどもなんだからよ。
> After all, you (prisoners) are idiots who are *<long description here>*.

The long relative clause contains several clauses:

> シャバにいたところで
> even outside the prison, (lit. "Even if you are in the free world,")
>
> [他人様の迷惑になること]**は**あっても
> who may trouble others but
> (look up the ～ことがある construction in case you did not know it)
>
> (他人様の)役に**は**立たない
> who are not of help (to others)

Notice the two contrastive-は's (bold). Therefore a translation would be:

> どうせシャバにいたところで他人様の迷惑になることはあっても役には立たないボンクラどもなんだからよ。
>
> After all, you guys are idiots who would only be troublesome but never helpful to others even if you were outside the prison.

Comment: @Chocolate ありがとうございます ＞＜

Comment: This is exactly the type of response I search for whenever I post! Thanks to all who replied!

Comment: @SomaRise Glad to hear that, but did you see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/719822)? :)

Comment: Oh. I must've missed that. This site seems to add neat little tidbits here and there every few months, I can't keep up. Like I responded above, I didn't even realized there had been an update to the otherwise Commodore 64 style word processing this site used to employ last year, now it looks great!

Comment: @SomaRise I'm pretty sure the text formatting function and the checking function have been around ever since this site was born in 2011...