# How is ことはあっても used in this sentence?

Tags: translation, て-form, sentence, particle-も

> 怒らない。。。の?

And his answer:

> 何言ってるんだ. 何日も懸命に頑張ってくれたのに。。。

> 感謝することはあっても

> 怒る理由がない

I understand the answer is akin "What are you saying? You did your best for us for so many days."

However I struggled to place 感謝することはあっても.  Obviously 怒る理由がない is "So there is no reason for me to get mad at you" but how does 感謝することはあっても work?

"Even if there is a reason to be thankful, I'm not mad at you" doesn't make sense.

Comment: If "even if" is too strong, "while" can be used to express this contrast. One literal translation would be "While I may be thankful, there is no reason (for me) to get mad at you". Or "There is a reason to appreciate this, but no reason to get angry".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the same as the following question:

[How does ことはあっても connect this otherwise 2 part sentence into one?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76344/45489)

I'm not sure what exactly makes it difficult to understand, but if the translation you got (which I think is reasonably correct) does not make sense, forget *if* and remember [も](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82/#jn-218351) is just 逆接=but.

So a literal translation is *I could be thankful, but there is no reason to get mad*. If this is still odd, just use *and* instead of *but* (which does not change the meaning logically).

As a pattern, AすることはあってもB(することは)ない means *A could happen, but B can't*. The emphasis is that B won't happen.

In the context, the first speaker A thinks they let down the second speaker in some way. Then the second speaker is saying, they could thank A for the efforts all the same and there is no reason to get mad at A.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone in being puzzled by this expression. Superficially, it looks like it should be 逆説, adversative, the two sentences joined with 'but', and the second sentence expressing some contrast or contradiction of the first.

We have two sentences,

感謝することはある

怒る理由がない

If we were to join these by sense, we would expect the like of

感謝することはあれば、怒る理由がない 'If [I] sometimes do apologize, there is no reason to get angry.'

quite differently from how it is in fact written.

In the normal case, ーても expresses a concession or contrast:

たとえ君が忠告しても止めないだろう 'Even if you cautioned [him], [he] wouldn't stop.'

But often, it can be read ambiguously or the sense of concession or contrast is muted, and the usage seems to amount to the same as ーては:

このことはヨウロッパの歴史を見ても明らかである　'This fact is clear if/(?)even if you look at the history of Europe.'

あの旅館は急に行っても泊まれないらしい '...if/(?)even if you go there straight away...'

お茶を飲んでも今夜は眠れますか 'If/(?)even if you drink tea, won't you be able to sleep tonight?'

Your example sentence is like this, the contrast/concessional meaning of ーても is attenuated, and it makes more sense (to non-natives) to think of it as ーては.

And this calls to mind a classical japanese/literary usage, using the 已然形 form of the verb (roughly, remove ば from the provisional) after こそ:

言うことこそ違え、考えは同じだ 'What is said differs, but the idea is the same.'

Again, in the normal case, there is an adversative (逆説) connection between the conjoined sentences. But there are uses of this construction where there is no hint of contrast, seeming to simply be 順接, and it especially seems to occur with the structure V-i koso sure:

恨まれこそすれ、そう笑顔を向けられるような存在じゃないはずですが。

(A wealth of examples can be found at [yourei.jp](https://yourei.jp/%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B))

According to [kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D-501939) there are very few examples, in classical Japanese, of its use, like this, to express a 順接 relation.